# What's wrong with my kendo template?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've prepared template for my Kendo Grid's column:

```
# if(status == 0) { # 
    #= "Error" #
# else if(status == 1) { #
    #= "Warning" #
# else if(status == 2) { #
    #= "OK" #
# } #
```

It's seems OK to me, but I'm getting an error "Error: Invalid template". Grid displays numeric values, but I'd like to replace it with string values.

So where's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket on the first and second if statement.

```
# if(status == 0) { # 
    #= "Error" #
# } else if(status == 1) { #
    #= "Warning" #
# } else if(status == 2) { #
    #= "OK" #
# } #
```

Comment: can you debug this: `# if(#'#=Value#'#.indexOf('.') == -1) ){# #= '$' + Value # #}else{# #= '$' + Value +'.00' # #}#` ? I am getting error and the grid is not getting generated.

I am trying to display `.00` if the `Value` field of the table doesn't have it already.